# Download repo as a zip file

Tags: git, curl, github

I am trying to download as a zip file a private GitHub repo.

I am trying:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token f19..." -L https://github.com/Mylab/name/archive/release.zip
```

and it shows me:

```
{"error":"Not found"}
```

If I try:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token f19..." -L -o release.zip https://github.com/Mylab/name/archive/release.zip
```

it downloads a very small zip file which I can't open because it says "Either this file is not zip ......".

Comment: Is your very small zip file around 22 bytes? If so it is probably the error message text with a .zip file extension.

Comment: @Owen:Yes,it is 21bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem

```
curl -H "Authorization: token f19..." -Lk https://api.github.com/repos/Mylab/name/zipball/release -o release.zip
```

**EDIT** : you need to customize :

- Mylab : user or organization
- name : repository name
- release : tag or branch targeted

**EDIT 2**: you need to have a [token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) that have the whole "repo" category ticked to grant you full access to private repositories

**EDIT 3**: beware there must be **only one** space between token and f19...

Comment: :It gives me again a small zip file 21 bytes and I can't unzip it.I used `zipball` as you have it , after the name, right?

Comment: :I am using the above but as I told you I am getting a 'wrong' zip file.

Comment: does your token grant you full access to repos ? Check there [setting](https://github.com/settings/tokens) .  ``repo`` (Full control of private repositories) must be checked for the token you are using. you could check it with the output of ``curl -H "Authorization: token f19..." -Lk https://api.github.com/repos/Mylab/name``

Comment: :Hmm..It shows 'Bad credentials'.In order to create OAuth, I went to settings-> Developer Applications ->Register a new Application.I created the ID.Do I need to do something else?Thanks!

Comment: no, a token is not a new application but a new "Personal access tokens".

Comment: :And what about the OAuth?I don't have to do anything with that?Also,regarding the personal token,what do I have to select in order only to download as zip a repo?

Comment: 0Auth is authentication mechanism provided by github. For example, [travis](https://travis-ci.org/) use it. When sign in with your github account, travis may have access to some of your data.

For you download, you just need to generate a token and make a check next to "repos" category

Comment: Access deployment status ?Only this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118818/discussion-between-george-and-jibe).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118829/discussion-between-george-and-jibe).

Answer (score 0):

The name after `/archive/` has to be the name of the branch you want to download.

Usually it's `master.zip` or `feature/my-feature.zip`, `release/my-release.zip` etc. Just `release.zip` sounds suspicious as `release/` is commonly only the prefix for the release branches in git.

So the correct URL/command are:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token f19..." -L https://github.com/Mylab/name/archive/master.zip 
curl -H "Authorization: token f19..." -L https://github.com/Mylab/name/archive/feature/my-feature.zip 
curl -H "Authorization: token f19..." -L https://github.com/Mylab/name/archive/release/august-release-001.zip
```

You can check the correct URL at the right on github, in the button **Clone or download** / **Download ZIP** when already chose correct branch from the list.

Comment: I tried `curl -H "Authorization: token f19..." -L -o release.zip https://github.com/Mylab/name/archive/release` and `curl -H "Authorization: token f19..." -L -o release.zip https://github.com/Mylab/name/tree/release ` but still the same

Comment: :I tried this but it gives me the `{"error":"Not found"}`.